# Copy files (from list) from any subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file that contains a list of files like this:

**Contents of list.txt:**

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I need to search through a directory (and it's subdirectories) to find each file and copy it into another directory.

Current directory: 
-dir
   -subdir1
   -subdir2
   -subdir3
   -subdir4
   -outputdir

**In this example, I might:**

- find `file1.txt` in `subdir3`
- find `file2.txt` in `subdir1`
- `file3.txt` might not exist

**In this case, it would copy `file1.txt` & `file2.txt` into `outputdir`**

I don't have much experience will doing this on the command line, but have 1200 files to move, so I can't do it manually.  This is the closest thing I've gotten to the right thing, but it doesn't find any of the files because they are all in subdirectories:

```
xargs -a list.txt cp -t outputdir
```

An explanation of the command you give would also be immensely helpful.  Searches around have also brought up "bash for loops", which I tried to use but couldn't figure out all the intricacies:

```
FOR /R "%~dp0" %%I IN (.) DO  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0list.txt") do echo d |xcopy "%%I\%%a" "outputdir" /e /i
```

Comment: Part of your problem is that last bit isn't `bash` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bash` 4, use the following:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    files=("$dir"/**/"$fname")
    if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
        cp "${files[@]}" "$outputdir"
    fi
done < list.txt
```

The `while` loop reads from `list.txt` one line at a time. The `**` pattern matches zero or more directories; `files` could contain 0 or more matching files. If the array is not empty, all file names are passed to `cp` for copying.

For older versions, use `find`:

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    find "$dir" -name "$fname" -type f -exec cp {} "$outputdir" \;
done < list.txt
```

This simply locates all matching files under `$dir` and runs `cp` on each.

Comment: Seems to work, but I'm getting errors and probably need to tweak the code.  Can you explain the code a bit so I can troubleshoot for my real stuff?